# Set a variable outside loop and fetch it every item of loop

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

My oracle version : `Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi`

I'm trying to set a variable outside loop and make its value change as the each item of loop. (Just like we usually do in jsp, php...)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST2 AS 
  -- VARIABLE
    v_variable number; 
    cursor c2 is
    select round(dbms_random.value() * 8) + 1 AS temp_key from dual; -- temp_key is a random value

BEGIN  
    OPEN c2;
    FOR SRC IN (SELECT * FROM TB_MASTER_TEMP2) -- it has many rows
     LOOP
        fetch c2 into v_variable; -- v_variable need to change for every row
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line(SRC.MAS_ENTRY_NM || ', ' ||v_variable); --test
     END LOOP;

END TEST2;
```

But the result is

```
aaa, 8
bbb, 8 --`v_variable` stays the same
...
```

`v_variable` doesn't change.
Please correnct my procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TEST2 AS 
-- VARIABLE
v_variable number; 
--cursor c2 is
--select round(dbms_random.value() * 8) + 1 AS temp_key from dual; -- temp_key is a random value

BEGIN  
--OPEN c2;
FOR SRC IN (SELECT * FROM TB_MASTER_TEMP2) -- it has many rows
 LOOP
    --fetch c2 into v_variable; -- v_variable need to change for every row
    select round(dbms_random.value() * 8) + 1 into v_variable from dual; 
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(SRC.MAS_ENTRY_NM || ', ' ||v_variable); --test
 END LOOP;

END TEST2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone has played silly buggers with it, `dual` has a single row, so the result set returned by `c2` also has a single row. Any attempt to fetch beyond the end of that result set will simply return the last (and only) row over and over again.

If you want to retrieve a *different* random value on each iteration of the loop, you need to execute your `SELECT ... FROM dual` *each time* you loop, as in @Utsav's code.

Comment: Now I understand it. I thought everytime `fetch` was called, it executes `select` and fetch into the variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hello i have slightly tweaked your code. It may help you. Since i dont have workspace with me so plz bear with any syntax errors.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST2
AS
  -- VARIABLE
  v_variable NUMBER;
BEGIN
  --  OPEN c2; -- Not required
  FOR SRC IN
  (SELECT t2.*,
    ROUND(dbms_random.value() * 8) + 1 AS temp_key
  FROM TB_MASTER_TEMP2 t2
  ) -- it has many rows
  LOOP
    -- v_variable need to change for every row
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(SRC.MAS_ENTRY_NM || ', ' ||src.temp_key); --test
  END LOOP;
END TEST2;
```